# Move files only if filename based regex does not match file in target dir

Tags: grep, find, ls, mv

Best explained by an example:

Source dir:

- file-a-1.txt
- file-b-1.txt

Target dir:

- file-a-2.txt

Expected result:

- file-a-2.txt
- file-b-1.txt

Move all files from src dir to target dir only if file from source dir to target dir if target dir does not have a file that partially matches the filename.

Comment: What do you mean by “partially matches”? Do you mean that they should differ only in one sequence of digits? Only in one sequence of digits immediately before the last dot in the file name? Only in one sequence of alphanumeric characters between the next-to-last punctuation mark and the last punctuation mark? Something else?

Comment: Solved it. Not relevant exactly what part should match, thats only the regex part.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

1. List files in target dir
2. Replace to wildcard match with sed
3. Pipe to rsync `--exclude-from`

`find target_dir | sed -r 's/\.\/(.+?)-.*/\1*/' | rsync --verbose --ignore-existing --exclude-from - src_dir/* target_dir`